# Logstash Grok overwrite not working

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-grok

I have the following logstash grok statements that should run if the field contains a string "Caused" in which case a different pattern is applied to it and it is overwritten but for some reason it does work. The regex patterns definitely work individually and the issue is in the the logic below. Any help appreciated, thanks

```
grok {
        patterns_dir => ["./patterns"]
        match => ["message", "%{GREEDYDATA}\n%{JAVA_EXCEPTION_SHORT:exception}"]
}

if [exception] =~ "Caused" {
         grok {
            patterns_dir => ["./patterns"]
            match => ["exception", "{JAVA_EXCEPTION_LONG:exception}"]
            overwrite => ["exception"]
        }
}
```

Custom Patterns:

```
JAVA_EXCEPTION_LONG (?<=^Caused by: ).*?Exception
JAVA_EXCEPTION_SHORT ^.+Exception
```

Example log message:

```
2016-11-15 05:19:28,801 ERROR [App-Initialisation-Thread] appengine.java:520 Failed to initialize external authenticator myapp Support Access || appuser@vm23-13:/mnt/data/install/assembly app-1.4.12@cad85b224cce11eb5defa126030f21fa867b0dad
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not check if provided root is a directory
    at com.myapp.io.AbstractRootPrefixedFileSystem.checkAndGetRoot(AbstractRootPrefixedFileSystem.java:67)
    at com.myapp.io.AbstractRootPrefixedFileSystem.<init>(AbstractRootPrefixedFileSystem.java:30)
    at com.myapp.io.s3.S3FileSystem.<init>(S3FileSystem.java:32)
    at com.myapp.io.s3.S3FileSystemDriver.loadFileSystem(S3FileSystemDriver.java:60)
    at com.myapp.io.FileSystems.getFileSystem(FileSystems.java:55)
    at com.myapp.authentication.ldap.S3LdapConfigProvider.initializeCloudFS(S3LdapConfigProvider.java:77)
    at com.myapp.authentication.ldap.S3LdapConfigProvider.loadS3Config(S3LdapConfigProvider.java:51)
    at com.myapp.authentication.ldap.S3LdapConfigProvider.getLdapConfig(S3LdapConfigProvider.java:42)
    at com.myapp.authentication.ldap.DelegatingLdapConfigProvider.getLdapConfig(DelegatingLdapConfigProvider.java:45)
    at com.myapp.authentication.ldap.LdapExternalAuthenticatorFactory.create(LdapExternalAuthenticatorFactory.java:28)
    at com.myapp.authentication.ldap.LdapExternalAuthenticatorFactory.create(LdapExternalAuthenticatorFactory.java:10)
    at com.myapp.frob.appengine.getExternalAuthenticators(appengine.java:516)
    at com.myapp.frob.appengine.startUp(appengine.java:871)
    at com.myapp.frob.appengine.startUp(appengine.java:754)
    at com.myapp.jsp.KewServeInitContextListener$1.run(QServerInitContextListener.java:104)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: fh-ldap-config/
    at com.upplication.s3fs.util.S3Utils.getS3ObjectSummary(S3Utils.java:55)
    at com.upplication.s3fs.util.S3Utils.getS3FileAttributes(S3Utils.java:64)
    at com.upplication.s3fs.S3FileSystemProvider.readAttributes(S3FileSystemProvider.java:463)
    at com.myapp.io.AbstractRootPrefixedFileSystem.checkAndGetRoot(AbstractRootPrefixedFileSystem.java:61)
```

Comment: Without any logs to test your conf against, I think the problem comes the comparison (`if [exception] =~ "Caused"`)

Comment: thanks @baudsp I have added the additional info, I have also tried this: if "Caused" in [exception] {}, but was also unsuccessful

Comment: But I feel like, the exception elaborates about a file missing? You sure the culprit is from the if condition?

Comment: The error message is an example of what would be parsed by the grok statements, not an output of ELK

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The grok filter fails because you're missing a `%` in this line:

```
match => ["exception", "{JAVA_EXCEPTION_LONG:exception}"]
```

It should look like this:

```
match => ["exception", "%{JAVA_EXCEPTION_LONG:exception}"]
```

Since the parsing failed, the field `exception` was not overwritten.

Comment: thank you! i can't believe I haven't noticed it!! It worked

Comment: @Arturski You're welcome! I discovered it while trying to test the pattern with grokconstructor.appspot.com/do/match#result, which is very useful to test grok patterns.